# Custom logging in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm new to ADF and trying to build an Azure Data Flow Pipeline. I'm reading from a Snowflake data source and checking the data against several business rules. After each check, I'm writing the bad records to a csv file. Now, my requirement is that I need to create a log table which shows the business rule and the number of records that failed to pass that particular business rule. I've attached a screenshot of my ADF data flow as well as the structure of the table I'm trying to populate.

My idea was to create a stored proc that will be called at the end of each business rule, so that a record is created in the database. However, I'm unable to add an SP from the data flow. I found that I can get the rows written to a sink from the pipeline. However, I am not getting as to how I can tie the sink name and the rows written together and iterate the stored procedure for all the business rules?

[Snapshot of how my data flow looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BJY6.png)

[The columns that I want to populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EhD0.png)

Comment: Do you copy data into separate sinks for every business rule violations? Records failed due to Business rule-1 is moved to sink1 ,Records failed due to business rule-2 in sink2 and so on.

Comment: @Sandeep Arikontham, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have considered **sink1** and **sink2** for storing the data that violates business-rule1 and rule2 respectively in my dataflow activity. I've created a stored procedure for recording the business rule and failed count in log-files. Then **execute stored procedure** activity in ADF is used and records are inserted in log files. Below are the steps.

- Table for log-file.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[log_file](
    [BusinessRule] [varchar](50) NULL,--Business Rule
    [count] [varchar](50) NULL--failed rows count
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

- Stored procedure for inserting records in log file through data factory.

```
Create proc [dbo].[usp_insert_log_file] (@BusinessRule varchar(100),@count varchar(10))
as
begin
insert into log_file values (@BusinessRule,@count)
end
```

-Dataflow activity has two sinks. It is chained with **execute Stored procedure** activity.

[image]

- Stored Procedure has two parameters,
  Enter the business rule in business_rule parameter and for count parameter,
- In Stored procedure 1, Enter the corresponding business rule for sink1 in BusinessRule field, and for count field, pass the sink1's rowsWritten value from the output of data flow activity.
  **BusinessRule:** `'Business_Rule_1'`

**Count:**

```
@string(activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten)`
```

[image]

- Similarly in Stored Procedure2 activity, pass the sink2 count value and enter the corresponding business rule in parameters

**BusinessRule:** `'Business_Rule_2'`
**Count:**

```
@string(activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.metrics.sink2.rowsWritten)
```

[image]

In this way, We can insert data to logfile from dataflow activity using exec stored procedure activity.

[image]